# Qt metaobject system: emit signal using a string with its name

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals, qmetaobject

Qt signal/slot system rocks, but looks that it lacks some really useful functionality (or at least I can't find how to use it). I have a class with lots of signals, and this class has a `switch` which needs to emit a proper signal depending on a variable's value. Now I solve this using C preprocessor:

```
#define CASE(_NAME) \    
case MyEnum_ ## _NAME: \
{ \
    emit MySignal_ ## _NAME(); \
    do_other_stuff(); \
    break; \
}

switch(val)
{
CASE(Val_1)
CASE(Val_2)
CASE(Val_3)
}
```

This just doesn't look right. I am sure there is a more elegant way. `QMetaObject` has an `indexOfSignal` method which can give me the Qt's internal ID of the signal using a string with its name. If I could emit a signal using this ID, my code would become *much* cleaner.

I've peeked at the signal method implementation generated by `moc`, and it looks like the the only thing that differs from one signal to another is a single digit:

```
void *_a[] = { 0, const_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<const void*>(&_t1)) };
QMetaObject::activate(this, &staticMetaObject, <signal_id>, _a);
```

where `<signal_id>` is an integer unique for each signal.

So, the question is, how do I `emit(int signalIdx)`? Or at least get a chance to call `QMetaObject::activate`, since it looks buried in private headers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use 
[QMetaObject::invokeMethod](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod)

I am using this in my program:

`mCaller` is object with defined slot and `mSlotName` is name of the slot

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mCaller, mSlotName.toLatin1().constData(), Qt::DirectConnection)
```

Comment: In your case it is of course signal name. Works the same.

Comment: Okay, this is embarrassing. I somehow thought that invokeMethod is used only for, well, invoking metamethods and slots, not for emitting signals.

Answer (score 3):

Although `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` is the better option, yet it's also possible to emit signal only by number: `emit p->metaObject()->method(n).invoke(...);`

Comment: Thank you. For some reason it didn't come to my mind that a signal is also a method which can be invoked.